# How do you return a string array inside a recursive function or copy it?

Tags: c, arrays, string, recursion

I have a problem at the add2_recur function. I am trying to add up a single character digit within a string. But I do not know how to return a string to my main function so I can print out the result. I try using function pointer but i only return the first value of the string.

Any suggestion on how to do this would be helpful.

```
//check if string is valid

int digcheck_helper(char *theno, int start, int length) {

         int charToInt = *(theno+start);

         if(!((charToInt >= 48) &&(charToInt <= 57)))
             return 0;
         if(length == 0)
             return 1;

         return digcheck_helper(theno,start+1,length-1);
}

int digcheck(char *str, int start, int length) {

         return digcheck_helper(string,start,length);
}

/**********************
 ****add recursive function**/

void add2_recur(char *num1, char *num2, int start, int carryDig) {

         int singleChar1 = *(num1 + start), singleChar2 = *(num2 + start);
         char *str = (char*) malloc(strlen(num1) + 2);

         sum = singleChar1 + singleChar - 96;

         if(carryDig == 1)
            sum = sum + 1;
         if(start < strlen(num1)) {

                if(sum >= 10) {

                    sum = sum - 10;
                    str[start] = sum + 48;
                    carryDig = 1;
                    printf("sum of single digit is: %c\n", str[start]);
                }
                else if( sum < 10) {

                    str[start] = sum + 48;
                    carryDig = 0;
                    printf("sum of single digit is: %c\n", str[start]);
               }

                    add2_recur(num1,num2,start+1,carryDig);
         }
         else if ((start == strlen(num1)) && (carryDig ==1)){ 
                    str[start+1] = 48;
                    printf("sum of single digit is: %c\n", str[start+1]);
         }
}

void add2(char *n1, char *n2) {

        add2_recur(n1,n2,0,0)

}


/*******************/

int main() {

         char string1[20000], string2[20000], revStr1[20000], revStr2[20000];
         int digit_1, digit_2, i;

         printf("Enter first number >");
         fgets(string1,20000,stdin);

         string1[strlen(string1)-1] = '\0';
         digit_1 = digcheck(string1,0,strlen(string1)-1);

         //Check if string is valid integer

         if(digit_1 = 0)
             printf("This number is invalid\n");
         else{

                printf("Enter second number >");
                fgets(string2,2000,stdin);

                string2[strlen(string2)-1] = '\0';
                digit_2 = digcheck(string2,0,strlen(string2-1);

                if(digit_2 == 0)
                     printf("This number is invalid\n");
                else
                     printf("1st num is %s\n2st num is %s\n", string1, string2);
         }


         // reverse string
          for(i=0;i<strlen(string1);i++)
               revStr1[i] = string1[(strlen(string1)-1) - i];

          for(i=0;i,strlen(string2);i++)
               revStr2[i] = string2[(strlen(string2) -1) - i];

         // compare string and pass to add2
          if(strlen(revStr1) < strlen(revStr2)) {

               for(i = strlen(revStr1); i < strlen(revStr2); i++)
                  revStr1[i] = '0';

               add2(revStr1,revStr2);
          }
          else if(strlen(revStr2) < strlen(revStr1)) {

                 for(i = strlen(revStr2); i < strlen(revStr1); i++)
                     revStr2[i] = '0';

                add2(revStr1,revStr2);
          }
          else 
                add2(revStr1,revStr2);


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: happens, what if, string is > 20000 chars?

Comment: oh, my professor said we can ignore that case. But each time i call a recursive function the value would not copy to the *str array

Comment: regarding these kind of lines: fgets(string1,20000,stdin);  the returned value from fgets() needs to be checked to assure the input operation was successful

Comment: this will not compile for several reasons including this line:  'sum = singleChar1 + singleChar - 96;'  references a variable: 'singleChar' but singleChar is not defined.  We really need posted code that 1) compiles and 2) shows the problem indicated in the question.

Comment: I would strongly suggest the OP add a check of each of the input values to assure it is <= 20000.  and perhaps write the code so the user could be allowed to retry entering the value(s)

Comment: there is over 80,000 bytes of stack allocated, in main() alone.  Stack is (usually) not excessively large.  rather than overrunning the stack size, suggest placing those huge arrays in file memory rather than stack memory

Comment: in this line: (and other other lines referencing the same variable) sum = singleChar1 + singleChar - 96;  The variable sum is not defined.  so this code will not compile.

Comment: in general, a recursive function should return the result of its' operation.  then (in this case) each prior function in the chain should post pend the returned value to what every the current instance of the function produces, then return that result to its' caller.  I would suggest, in this instance that the addition start with the right most char of each string and work toward the left, as the current code 'seems' to be starting from the left and working toward the right.  The code also needs to handle the situation where the two strings are different lengths

Comment: Hi, i basically reverse the string in the main function and padded the string with '0' character to make the length equal. Everything should compile. I think i might have mistype the code since i could not paste the code here. It's just that i am not sure how to return a string array back to the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C something like this is typically achieved by not `return`ing the actual string. Instead you can just work with a pointer to a buffer passed to you. Use the actual return value to report status messages instead.

To not spoil the actual task for you, let's define a simple recursive function that will return a string with all non-alphanumerical characters being stripped:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strip_stuff_rec(const char *input, char *output, unsigned int offset_input, unsigned offset_output) {
    // Retrieve the character and move the offset
    const char c = input[offset_input++];

    if (c == '\0') { // Terminator; we're done!
        // Terminate the output string
        output[offset_output] = '\0';
        return 1; // Signal success
    }

    // Character is alphanumeric?
    if (isalnum(c)) {
        // Append the character to our result and move the offset
        output[offset_output++] = c;
    }

    // To have an error case, let's just pretend the string must not include @!
    if (c == '@') {
        return 0; // Signal an error
    }

    // Now handle the next position
    return strip_stuff_rec(input, output, offset_input, offset_output);
}

int strip_stuff(const char *input, char *output) {
    // Reset the output
    output[0] = '\0';
    // Start the recursive calls
    return strip_stuff_rec(input, output, 0, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // First let's set some input string
    const char *input = "Hello World! -- I've had a wonderful day!";
    // And we'll need a buffer for our result
    char result[256];

    // Now call the function and check the return value to determine
    // whether it's been successful.
    if (strip_stuff(input, result) == 0) {
        printf("Some error happened!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("The stripped string is '%s'.\n", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this function:

void add2(char *n1, char *n2) 
{
    add2_recur(n1,n2,0,0)
}

this function has a couple of problems.
1) it will not compile because the statement that calls add2-recur() 
   is missing a trailing ';'

2) this function is not needed as add2_recur can be called directly

3) this is expected to add two numbers together .. 
   How is it to return the result?  
   It (probably) should be more like:

void add2(char *n1, char *n2, char *sum) 
{
    strcpy(sum, add2_recur(n1,n2,0,0) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i fix the code by creating a pointer function and storing the value into the **str** array by using malloc. I commented out the code. But it still only return the first element of the array to the main function from the heap. How do i get it to return the whole array?

//check if string is valid

int digcheck_helper(char *theno, int start, int length) {

```
     int charToInt = *(theno+start);

     if(!((charToInt >= 48) &&(charToInt <= 57)))
         return 0;
     if(length == 0)
         return 1;

     return digcheck_helper(theno,start+1,length-1);
```

}

int digcheck(char *str, int start, int length) {

```
     return digcheck_helper(string,start,length);
```

}

/**********************
 ****add recursive function**/

char *add2_recur(char *num1, char *num2, int start, int carryDig) {

```
     int singleChar1 = *(num1 + start), singleChar2 = *(num2 + start);
     char *str = (char*) malloc(strlen(num1) + 2), sum;

     sum = singleChar1 + singleChar - 96;

     if(carryDig == 1)
        sum = sum + 1;
     if(start < strlen(num1)) {

            if(sum >= 10) {

                sum = sum - 10;
                str[start] = sum + 48; //store value in each element of an array
                carryDig = 1;
                printf("sum of single digit is: %c\n", str[start]);
            }
            else if( sum < 10) {

                str[start] = sum + 48; //store value in each element of an array
                carryDig = 0;
                printf("sum of single digit is: %c\n", str[start]);
           }

                add2_recur(num1,num2,start+1,carryDig);
     }
     else if ((start == strlen(num1)) && (carryDig ==1)){ 
                str[start+1] = 49; // store value in each element of an array
                printf("sum of single digit is: %c\n", str[start+1]);
     }

      return str;
```

}

/*******************/

int main() {

```
     char string1[20000], string2[20000], revStr1[20000], revStr2[20000], *addResult;
     int digit_1, digit_2, i;

     printf("Enter first number >");
     fgets(string1,20000,stdin);

     string1[strlen(string1)-1] = '\0';
     digit_1 = digcheck(string1,0,strlen(string1)-1);

     //Check if string is valid integer

     if(digit_1 = 0)
         printf("This number is invalid\n");
     else{

            printf("Enter second number >");
            fgets(string2,2000,stdin);

            string2[strlen(string2)-1] = '\0';
            digit_2 = digcheck(string2,0,strlen(string2-1);

            if(digit_2 == 0)
                 printf("This number is invalid\n");
            else
                 printf("1st num is %s\n2st num is %s\n", string1, string2);
     }


     // reverse string
      for(i=0;i<strlen(string1);i++)
           revStr1[i] = string1[(strlen(string1)-1) - i];

      for(i=0;i,strlen(string2);i++)
           revStr2[i] = string2[(strlen(string2) -1) - i];

     // compare string and pass to add2
      if(strlen(revStr1) < strlen(revStr2)) {

           for(i = strlen(revStr1); i < strlen(revStr2); i++)
              revStr1[i] = '0';

           add2(revStr1,revStr2);
      }
      else if(strlen(revStr2) < strlen(revStr1)) {

             for(i = strlen(revStr2); i < strlen(revStr1); i++)
                 revStr2[i] = '0';

           addResult = add2(revStr1,revStr2);
      }
      else 
            addResult = add2(revStr1,revStr2);


     // print out
     printf("sum is: %s\n", addResult);

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since passing the whole array is not very optimal, C usually in most of the expressions convert it to pointer.

One way to pass whole array is by enclosing it in a struct. (Not a good solution though)

```
typedef struct
{
   char s[128];
}MYSTR;
```